# Multiple custom fonts in text view / data from android.fromHtml

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have some Html data which looks something like this

```
<h1>This is a long headline</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<blockquote>This is a nice quote</blockquote>
```

My question:
Is there a way to assign multiple different custom fonts for each recognized tag? e.g.

- H1 > customFont1_black.otf
- p > customFont1_book.otf
- blockquote > customFont2_italic.otf

Note: We're using already `android.fromHtml` and assigned a single custom font. Though, like I described we need to assign multiple.

The Data/HTML is provided via an API, so I don't have access to the code.

Many thanks!

Comment: You're question is kinda strange, pls can you make it more clearing??? if you can get access to the String value, then you can apply custom fonts to it by simple downloading the fonts you needed and importing them to the font directory in you project, and then you can do something like this textView.setTypeface(resources.getFont(R.font.open_sans_light)); if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We're are already using custom fonts, that's not the problem. We want to use multiple custom fonts at the same time. Like I wrote, we have some input data which is provided via HTML. Currently we use android.fromHtml to display the text. That works fine with a single custom font, but we would like to assign multiple font-faces for each html tag. So far we can't see a way to get single responses/callback functions per individual html tag to achieve something like this.

Comment: can you show more codes? it doesn't sound like a problem actually.